# How to include form field attributes based on state in React?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, accessibility

I am trying to make an accessible form in React and I need to toggle the attribute `aria-describedby` based on the state of the field (i.e., if it has an error associated with it).

I know how to toggle the value of the attribute, but with regards to WCAG, a present but empty attribute of this type will fail. The entire attribute needs to be fully present or fully absent. Anything I try in-line throws errors and breaks the render.

To give an example, this is what I've been trying:

```
<label>
    <input type="text" name="someName" ref="someRef" {!this.state.isValid ? aria-describedby="helperText" : ''} required />
    <p id="helperText">Helper text for this form field.</p>
</label>
```

Again though, an empty attribute value for `aria-describedby` is invalid.

Is there any way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spread it like this:

```
<input type="text" 
     name="someName" 
     ref="someRef" 
     {... !this.state.isValid && {'aria-describedby': 'helperText'} } 
     required />
```

This is basically [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) usage.

Comment: Wow, thanks, not only for the quick response but for a solid solution. Had no idea!